# Python JSON parse duplicate records

Tags: python, json

In my JSON file I have sequence of same-named records

```
"ability_upgrades":{
    "ability":5155,
    "time":1226
},
"ability_upgrades":{
    "ability":5155,
    "time":1426
},
"ability_upgrades":{
    "ability":5155,
    "time":1497
},
"ability_upgrades":{
    "ability":5157,
    "time":1543
},
```

If I will use `json.loads` it will save only last of that records.
What I have to do if I want a list of `ability_upgrades`?

Comment: Are you in any position to change the file format? Because this JSON is horribly broken, and broken JSON is as much of a bug as any TypeError or kernel panic. It's not clear whether you're asking about how to format your JSON properly or how to force your code to read it despite the errors.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I know. It is not real JSON ofc. It is output of dota2 game log. I just make it JSON-like with some regex manipulations to easy-parse.

Comment: Then why not generate something valid, like a list of objects instead of an object with the same key over and over, or even a stream of separate objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#repeated-names-within-an-object) says a parameter called `object_pairs_hook` in `json.loads`  can be used for handling duplicated records:

```
>>> json.loads(s, object_pairs_hook=(lambda x:  x))
[(u'ability_upgrades', [(u'ability', 5155), (u'time', 1226)]), (u'ability_upgrades', [(u'ability', 5155), (u'time', 1426)]), (u'ability_upgrades', [(u'ability', 5155), (u'time', 1497)]), (u'ability_upgrades', [(u'ability', 5157), (u'time', 1543)])]
```

How that function is defined is totally depending on what you want it to be. In the example above, since that hook gets as parameters a list of pairs, the identity function simply gives the list back.

E.g., if you define:

```
def collectAbilityUpgrades(s):
    d = {}
    for k, v in s:
        if k not in d:
            d[k] = []
        d[k].append(v)
    return d
```

Then:

```
>>> json.loads(s, object_pairs_hook=collectAbilityUpgrades)
{u'ability_upgrades': [{u'ability': [5155], u'time': [1226]}, {u'ability': [5155], u'time': [1426]}, {u'ability': [5155], u'time': [1497]}, {u'ability': [5157], u'time': [1543]}]}
```

Which probably is similar to what you want.

Comment: Reading the fine documentation...gosh what a novel concept! Good implementation of a suitable hook, too. +1